# Preventing RDP screen to go black when minimized

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, mstsc

I am running some automated scripts on VM nodes and using certain tools to create a video capture of whatever is happening on the screen. One of the limitations of the video capturing software is that the screen on the remote machine must be rendered, meaning that I must have an active RDP session to the VM as long as I want the screen to be captured. That all works fine when I create an RDP session (mstsc) to that VM and leave it on my screen. However, when I minimize the RDP session, it seems like the remote screen becomes black and as a result prevents video capture.

I wonder where there is a way I can force the RDP session to render the screen as usual, even when the window is minimized?

Answer (score -1):

When minimized, RDP may not redraw the GUI, hence causing the problem. 
In registry, go here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\
```

Create new DWORD value with name:

```
RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized
```

Give value as 2.
Save it and now it should work.